# Auto correct on ASUS Zenfone

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct

I switched from an LG phone to a new ASUS Android phone and I am missing a feature on the ASUS. On my LG I used auto correct on the keyboard in a way that displayed suggestions but did not correct what I typed. If I decided to use the suggested word I only had to touch the suggestion and it replaced the mistyped word. On the ASUS, using the preinstalled ZenUI keyboard, I don't know how only to show the suggested words while typing. Whenever I switch on display of suggested words to be shown, they replace what I type as soon as I press space.

I want suggested words to be shown but not replace what I type unless I select a suggested word. This worked on my LG like a charm.

Now I have the option to switch off auto correction and then I get many mistyped words. If I switch suggested words on it is even worse, because auto correction chooses words I don't want by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the official [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) since it has the exact feature you mention, where suggested words are shown.  I have all automatic corrections completely turned off in its settings, and it works well without anything unexpected.